# bash script fail with more then one parameters

Tags: bash, function, ubuntu, parameter-passing

I have the following script:

```
function unpack(){
echo "starting";
SaveFolder=/home/"$USER"/Desktop/folde

for var in "$@"
do

if [ -f "$var" ] || [ -d "$var" ]  ; then

case [ file -b in "$var"   ]

  *directory*)
    echo  "file is directory"

    ;;

  *Zip*)
    echo  "file is Zip, use unZip"
    unzip -o $1 -d "$SaveFolder"
    ;;


   *gzip*)
   echo   "file is gzip, use gunzip"
   cp $1   "$SaveFolder"
   gunzip -N -d -f  "$SaveFolder"/$1;

   ;;

    *bzip2*)
     echo   "file is bunzip2, use bunzip"
     bzip2 -dk $1
    cp $1 "$SaveFolder"/
    bzip2 -d -f "$SaveFolder"/$1;
    ;;

   *compress*)
   echo  "uncompress file ending, use ncompress"
    ;;

  *)
      echo "not a valid file"
    ;;
esac
fi
done
}
```

It is working well when I am calling the function with one argument, for example:

```
unpack test.zip
```

but if I try:

```
unpack test.zip test.bz2
```

I get this error:

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of archive.bz2 or
archive.bz2.zip, and cannot find archive.bz2.ZIP, period.

Comment: Do you know what `case [ ... ]` does? Using `file` there is definitely wrong, maybe you wanted `$(...)` instead?

Comment: why? isn't case [ ... ] simply a switch case?

Comment: What is going on in `case [ file -b in "$var"   ]`?  `isn't case [ ... ] simply a switch case?` yes, but it's `case string in string)`. There is no `[` `]`.

Comment: You probably meant `case "$(file -b in "$var")"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean modified version of the code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

function unpack
{
    echo "starting"

    local -r SaveFolder=$HOME/Desktop/folde

    local var
    for var in "$@"; do
        if [[ ! -e $var ]]; then
            printf "WARNING: '%s' does not exist\\n" "$var" >&2
            continue
        fi

        case $(file -bi -- "$var") in
            'inode/directory;'*)
                printf "'%s' is a directory\\n" "$var"
                ;;

            'application/zip;'*)
                printf "'%s' is a Zip file, use unZip\\n" "$var"
                unzip -o -d "$SaveFolder" -- "$var"
                ;;

            'application/gzip;'*)
                printf "'%s' is a gzip file, use gunzip\\n" "$var"
                cp -- "$var" "$SaveFolder"
                gunzip -N -d -f -- "$SaveFolder/$var"
                ;;

            'application/x-bzip2;'*)
                printf "'%s' is a bzip2 file, use bunzip\\n" "$var"
                bzip2 -dk -- "$var"
                cp -- "$var" "$SaveFolder"
                bzip2 -d -f -- "$SaveFolder/$var"
                ;;

            'application/x-compress;'*)
                printf "'%s' is a compress file, use uncompress\\n" "$var"
                ;;

            *)
                printf "'%s' is not a supported file\\n" "$var"
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

- I localized the `SaveFolder` and `var` variables to avoid potential clashes with variables used in other functions.  It's generally a good idea to localize variables that are only used within a function.
- The test for existence of the file now uses just `-e`.  The old test was not reliable because there are are things that may be found in filesystems that are neither files nor directories (e.g. fifos, sockets, devices).
- Use the `-i` (`--mime`) option to `file` to get output that is easier and more reliable to process with a program.
- Replaced most uses of `echo` with `printf`.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).
- Fixed the broken `case` line.
- Replaced uses of `$1` with `"$var`".  I guess the code wasn't fully updated when the function was updated to take more than one argument.
- Generally added quoting (as recommended by [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)) go avoid breakages if input files contain whitespace or shell globbing metacharacters in their names.  See the [When Should You Quote?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) section of [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- Added `--` to commands as necessary to prevent problems if an input file has a name that begins with `-`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #2 (cp $file $target)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target).
- Note that I've done only very cursory testing on the commands for unpacking files.  There may be problems with some of them.